# Unix: Keeping an instance of flash player running as a daemon...?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm pretty new to unix operating systems. I'm running CentOS 6.5, and I need to run 1 (or more ideally) instances of Flash Player continually in the background, I've no idea how to do this.

The reason is because in Flash I'm using the RTMFP protocol to send data between clients P2P, and it would be useful for me to have a few test clients running on my server all the time.

How would I go about doing this? The flash program needs to be visually navigated through its menus to get it into the state required. Currently I'm just using putty, what can I install to get a GUI to do this, and how might I go about getting Flash Player (10.1 up) to work?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I think I have an idea what you're trying to do. To clarify, you want to have several flash applications running in browsers or via a flash player to act as test users to test your RTMFP protocol?

If this is the case, use VNC (something like running multiple instances of x11vnc on different ports) to log into several GUI accounts on your system and run the application (Linux is multiuser by default). You can close out the VNC without ending your session. This should work for what I think you're trying to do.

Hope this helps.